# .git-ftp-ignore file is not ignoring folder

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I have the `scss/` folder in the root of the project, since the first commit I've added that folder to the `.git-ftp-ignore` file, so it's not working, every push to PROD that folder is uploaded again.

I'm using `git ftp` through *Bitbucket pipelines*

Is there any way to *clean* the FTP cache like `git rm -r --cached .`?

Comment: if you have already commited the file or folder then the .gitignore will not ignore it despite having it properly ignored in the gitignore. You must first delete (`git rm <path>`) it so the tracks stop, and then add the file/folder to the .gitignore and the commit again.

Comment: Hey Victor the question is related to the `.git-ftp-ignore` file instead of `.gitignore`. I made those changes but didn't work.

Comment: ok!! sorry to hear that it didn't work out friend! hope you find the answer!